# Mockito testing a method that has a step that calls a gateway service

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, circuit-breaker

I am implementing a circuit breaker solution to my code using the [Spring-Breaker project](https://developmentsprint.github.io/spring-breaker/site/0.0.1/documentation.html) and was writing the test cases for the same.

Consider the following example:

```
@CircuitBreaker
methodA() {
    //some code
    gatewayServiceCall()
    //some code
}
```

I need to test methodA and make it fail using CircuitBreaker timeout so I wrote a test class that mocks this.

```
setup() {
    gatewayService = mock(GatewayService.class);
    when(gatewayService.methodName().thenReturn(something);
}

@Test
testMethodA() {
    methodA();
}
```

How do I make sure I call the methodA() but also mock the gatewayServiceCall.

I hope the question was clear. Please let me know if it wasn't. I'll try to elaborate further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an Answer that sleeps:

```
final Foo fooFixture = new Foo();
Answer<Foo> answer = new Answer<Foo>() {

    @Override
    public Foo answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        return fooFixture ;
    }
};
when(gatewayService.methodName()).thenAnswer(answer);
```

Comment: Steve, that's the problem. The test ends up calling methodA() but executes the gateway service call in the original class and not the mocked one.

Comment: So, you question has nothing to do with Circuit Breakers and timeout?  You just don't know how to use Mockito?